# What is the best way to travel from IST to Istanbul?

Tags: airport-transfer, turkey, istanbul, isl

Is there an airport link or subway which takes you from the IST airport to somewhere close to the Hagia Sophia neighbourhood?  I am looking at either taking a cab or the public transit to get to the city.  Any recommendations?

Comment: if you have a layover and are planning a little self-guided touring, your best bet may be the free tour the airport provides. It's well described in other Istanbul questions here.

Answer (score 6):

You've got three sensible options: taxi, bus, or train.

- **Taxis** are taxis, and they're generally fine, although I've heard the occasional horror story; get a regular cab from the rank and use the meter, the fare should be 35-40 TL.
- Non-stop airport express **buses** are operated by [Havataş](http://havatas.com.tr/), charging a flat fare of 10 TL.  They serve a variety of places in the city, the closest to Sultanahmet being Yenikapi, from where you can take a taxi onwards.  The Yenikapi service doesn't run very often though, while the Taksim service is frequent but not particularly convenient.
- The M1 **metro** goes from the airport to Aksaray, where you can transfer to the T1 tram to Sultanahmet.  Cheap (a bit over 3 TL with an Istanbulkart smart card) but slow and a bit confusing.

All things considered, if you're a first-time visitor, I'd take the taxi.

Comment: I took the metro, I changed one time and were directly in front of the blue mosque. easy.

Comment: Is the metro and tram part of the same system or different so that you have to pay different fares.

Comment: @ThierryLam different.

Comment: can you please also see [this](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/176647/travel-from-saw-airport-istanbul-to-europe-side-of-istanbul-via-metro)

Comment: THIS ANSWER REFERS TO THE OLD IST AIRPORT!  IST airport has since moved to a new location, and the options provided in this option are not necessarily correct.  (eg, the Metro line does not currently extend to the new airport, and a taxi will cost far more than status)

Comment: @Doc I think you meant "stated"?