# Travel with luggage via Metro or Bus from SAW Airport Istanbul to Europe Side of Istanbul

Tags: trains, buses, turkey, istanbul, saw

I will be arriving at SAW airport with 30kg luggage. I want to know if its possible to travel to Europe side from the airport using metro/bus?

I am planning to buy Istanbulcard Anonymous Card  from the airport as the fares are merely $3.24 compared to $60 by taxi.

My concern is the 30 kg luggage, will it be possible to travel this way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Whilst it is possible to make that trip using some combination of Metro/Public Bus/Ferry, the best option is instead to catch one of the airport buses run by either [Havabus](https://havabus.com/) or [Havaist](https://hava.ist/).  These leave SAW roughly every 30 minutes, 24 hours a day (Havaist only for the 24 hours/day), and have dedicated luggage storage under the bus.

These buses will take you to either Taksim (Europe side) or Kadıköy (Asian side). Which of those destinations is the best option will depend on exactly where you're headed on the Europe side, however given the luggage you'll have the best option is likely to head to Taksim and then take a taxi (or Metro) from there to your accommodation. Alternatively you can catch a ferry from Kadıköy to somewhere near your accommodation (eg, Eminönü, Karaköy, Kabataş or Beşiktaş) and catch a taxi/Metro from there.

Whilst not the outright cheapest option, it's far cheaper than a taxi, and the best compromise between price, convenience and time - especially given you are carrying luggage.

Comment: Ok I just got intouch with Havaist using whatsapp service and looks like they allow 2 luggage under 30 kg. The price is 50 TL which is reasonable!